# vertical-align equivalent in CSS3

Tags: css

What is CSS3 equivalent property for vertical-align or vlalign of CSS? What if we need to implement it in different browsers, such as Chrome or Mozilla? Do we need to prefix -moz or -webkit before that specific property for different browser support?

Comment: there is no such thing as equivalent property to `vertical-align` in css, it's just a type of its own, we don't have property aliases

Comment: The `vertical-align` property is part of “CSS3”, too, since by default “CSS3” (a collective noun for a mix of specs and drafts) contains everything in CSS 2.1.

Comment: To shareef: I want to make a select box centric to the containing div. vertical-align property is not working.

Comment: Then you're not asking the right question.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

Try this on your containing div:

```
div { 
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Alternatively, another option is to set the CSS on your element to:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
height: 50px; //you need to set a fixed height, otherwise it will stretch
```

Of course, you'll need `position: relative;` on your container.

Both solutions will result in vertically centered content.